# Will bitshift and arithmetic operations be evaluated by the precompiler?

Tags: c++, precompile

If I define the following in a C++98 program:

```
#define BITS_PER_FOO 2
#define BITS_PER_BAR 3
#define FOOBARS (1<<(BITS_PER_FOO*BITS_PER_BAR))
```

then will `FOOBARS` get evaluated as 64 by the precompiler?  Or will a multiplication and bit-shift operation take place at each location that I use `FOOBARS` in the code?

Comment: Do you mean preprocessor? The preprocessor just replaces `FOOBARS` with `(1<<(2*3))`. The compiler then optimizes this expression to 64 in compile time.

Answer (score 2):

No, since it's not the preprocessor's business. It does the usual replace thing, not constant folding.

However, any reasonable compiler will do constant folding, so you should not expect this to correspond to instructions being executed at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The precompiler just does text substitution - it's essentially copy & paste on steroids. This means that the expression you wrote for `FOOBAR` will be expanded in full at each replacement location.

Now, any decent compiler will evaluate that whole subexpression at compile time anyway. However, you can save it some work (and have some extra advantages, like having a clear type of your expression, clearer diagnostic, less surprises deriving from substitutions in the wrong places, and having an actual lvalue for your constants instead of expressions) by defining these values as actual constants, like:

```
const int bits_per_foo = 2;
const int bits_per_bar = 3;
const int foobars = 1<<(bits_per_foo*bits_per_bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

A multiplication and bit-shift operation will take place at each location that you use `FOOBARS`.

See:  [#define Directive (C/C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx)

`#define` forms a macro, meaning the identifier is replaced with everything in the token-string.  In your case, the preprocessor replaces instances of `FOOBARS` with the expression `(1<<(BITS_PER_FOO*BITS_PER_BAR))`